# Revoke permissions from readonly_role

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres user named `readonly_role`

I would like to revoke the execute permission `pg_advisory_lock` with the following statement:

`revoke execute on function pg_advisory_lock from readonly_role;`

However this gives the error:

> ERROR:  function name "pg_advisory_lock" is not unique
> HINT:  Specify the argument list to select the function unambiguously.

What am I missing in trying to revoke this function?

Comment: As the error message suggests, `pg_advisory_lock` is an overloaded function, i.e. there are multiple functions of that name with different signatures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, you must specify the exact argument list in order to revoke execute permission for an overloaded function. This is how:

```
REVOKE EXECUTE ON FUNCTION pg_advisory_lock(integer, integer) FROM readonly_role;
```

To correspond with the particular overloaded variant of the function, modify the argument list.

Comment: Strangely, I still get this warning when trying to revoke `WARNING:  no privileges could be revoked for "pg_advisory_lock"`
But I am still able to execute the function. Any idea there?